# Html – space that does not break to a new line?

Tags: html

I'm working on a french webpage. Those crazy people make spaces before their question-marks and expclamation marks. We all know about `&nbsp;` but is there an equivalent that does not break the line?

Comment: Like CSS' `white-space:nowrap`?

Comment: yes, but a charcter, it's called hard space in word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

French orthography uses a “thin nonbreaking space” in the context of some punctuation marks. It is not clear how this concept should be mapped to Unicode. Using NO-BREAK SPACE would prevent a line break, which is good, but it is too wide (the same width as a normal space). There are different ways to deal with this; see my page [HTML authoring in French](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/french.html). Perhaps the best approach is to use NO-BREAK SPACE but set its width in CSS, e.g.

```
 Voilà<span class=fine>&nbsp;</span>!
```

with

```
.fine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.125em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` and set your white-space property in nowrap.

```
yourLinePClass {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a Unicode Nonbreaking space: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

Comment: The entity reference `&nbsp;`, mentioned in the question, denotes the no-break space.

Answer (score 0):

just use `white-space: nowrap;` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about < nobr >

Or

```
.question:after { content: "\0022"; }


<span class="question">Why God, why</span>
```